# How can use Ruby - Poltergeist (with PhantomJS) in a thread?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, poltergeist

I using Poltergeist to scrapping some sites in html5, then I use Nokogiri for parse HTML. With one page it's works relative fine, but with many (running other code) doesn't work, the first page works fine, but the others in other process doesn't work.
So I understand that I can't use many Poltergeist connections at the same time.

There's a way that I can load many pages at the same time using Poltergeist ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked of the people who [wrote and maintain it](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist)?